# Parsing float stored as string should throw Exception

Tags: java, parsing

I have a string which stores a number. Now i want to parse that string and get as float.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        try {
            System.out.println(Integer.parseInt("  2  "));
        } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception caught");
        }
        System.out.println(Float.parseFloat("  2.4  "));

    }
}
```

Now in the above code if you run it it will be successfull. My QUESTION is this why does trailing spaces in case of integer throws a `NumberFormatException` while parsing a float doesnt throw one ?

PS: Same is the case with booolean and double parsing.

PPS: Why is there an inconsistency in java ? And i already check the source code

Comment: why don't you have a look at the source code and learn?  Or look at @jens answer ;-)

Comment: @ScaryWombat It shouldn't be necessary to get the source code of Java and read it to know what a method does; that info should be in the method's JavaDoc. In this case the JavaDoc of `Float.parseFloat(String)` doesn't say that, but it says _...as performed by the valueOf method of class Float..._, and the JavaDoc of `Float.valueOf(String)` does say _Leading and trailing whitespace characters in s are ignored_.

Comment: @SantiBailors Thanks - Excellent comment

Comment: Calling this _an inconsistency in java_ is a bit of a stretch. They are two different methods. Like you, I don't see a reason for this difference either, but such reason should be asked to the designers, and there might be a good reason or not. Those are still two different methods to parse two different types of values and it's not wise to assume that they treat their argument in the same way.

Comment: seems like Oracle forget to place `string.trim()` in `parseInt()`

Comment: there has to be a reason, but the one who do the code forgot to add comments maybe, and then here we are solving this mystery hmmmm.

Comment: @daotan and Shaishav The authors did not forget to trim in parseInt and did not forget to add the JavaDoc comment. They did mention the trimming (see above) for Float because it trims, and did not mention the trimming for Integer because it does not trim. What they did not mention is the reason for this difference, but the reasons for the design decisions are not something a method's JavaDoc should be necessarily expected to mention.

Answer (score 3):

As you can see in the related source code, the value will be trimmed:

```
static FloatingDecimal.ASCIIToBinaryConverter readJavaFormatString(String arg) throws NumberFormatException {
    boolean arg0 = false;
    boolean arg1 = false;

    try {
        arg = arg.trim();
     ....
```

So the blanks will be removed before converting to a floatValue.
For more informations see the sourcecode of [FloatingDecimal](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/misc/FloatingDecimal.java) which is called by `Float.class`.

`Integer.parseInt()` do not trimm the string value:

```
public static int parseInt(String arg, int arg0) throws NumberFormatException {
    if (arg == null) {
        throw new NumberFormatException("null");
    } else if (arg0 < 2) {
        throw new NumberFormatException("radix " + arg0 + " less than Character.MIN_RADIX");
    } else if (arg0 > 36) {
        throw new NumberFormatException("radix " + arg0 + " greater than Character.MAX_RADIX");
    } else {
        int arg1 = 0;
        boolean arg2 = false;
        int arg3 = 0;
        int arg4 = arg.length();
        int arg5 = -2147483647;
        if (arg4 > 0) {
            char arg8 = arg.charAt(0);
            if (arg8 < 48) {
                if (arg8 == 45) {
                    arg2 = true;
                    arg5 = MIN_VALUE;
                } else if (arg8 != 43) {
                    throw NumberFormatException.forInputString(arg);
                }

                if (arg4 == 1) {
                    throw NumberFormatException.forInputString(arg);
                }

                ++arg3;
            }

            int arg7;
            for (int arg6 = arg5 / arg0; arg3 < arg4; arg1 -= arg7) {
                arg7 = Character.digit(arg.charAt(arg3++), arg0);
                if (arg7 < 0) {
                    throw NumberFormatException.forInputString(arg);
                }

                if (arg1 < arg6) {
                    throw NumberFormatException.forInputString(arg);
                }

                arg1 *= arg0;
                if (arg1 < arg5 + arg7) {
                    throw NumberFormatException.forInputString(arg);
                }
            }

            return arg2 ? arg1 : -arg1;
        } else {
            throw NumberFormatException.forInputString(arg);
        }
    }
}
```

Thats why you get an Exception there